# Not detecting ethereum provider on Metamask App for android

Tags: javascript, metamask, ethers.js

**TL;DR**
A simple `(typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') ? 'META YES' : 'META NO'` is saying no on android, but yes on all other platforms.

Hi all, so I have a completely stripped down react app that isn't even rendering JSX anymore because i've stripped it so far back. Basically I have an index that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And an index.tsx file that looks like this:

```
const metamask = (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') ? 'META YES' : 'META NO'

const doc = document.getElementById('root');

if(doc) {
  doc.innerHTML = metamask
}
```

Essentially, just show META YES if i have an `ethereum` object on the window, otherwise META NO.

Now, on IOS (via the MetaMask App Browser) and on desktop (With MetaMask Extension), I get  META YES.
But on android (via the MetaMask App Browser), I get META NO.

And i can't think, for the life of me, why i would be getting a no, especially only on one platform. Any ideas?

It's currently hosted via a HTTPS tunnel, so its running on a secure layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On android, press and hold metamask icon, go to app information, memory, "force stop". Try again. It worked for me after doing that, except for eth_requestAccounts method.